# Add duplicate tab

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-3.5, tabcontrol

I have created a tab in the designer and would like to add this tab each time a button is clicked with some different data in it.

When I run the following code:

```
this.tabsData.TabPages.Add("tabDatabaseTables", databaseName);
```

A tab is added, but the controls set in that tab do not appear.

I would like the controls to also appear.

Comment: Can't you just use the [TabControl.TabPageCollection.Add Method (TabPage) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68d9sedf.aspx)?

Comment: I could, but if I want to add two or three instances of `tabDatabaseTables`, how would I set the data for each instance?

Comment: Hypothetically, if you would copy the controls, what is the expected behavior for the event handlers of the copied controls (should they call the same methods as the original ones)?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Yes. The only difference is the data shown in those controls.

Comment: If you need to duplicate the TabPage, the easiest path is to create a UserControl and just dock fill it into a new TabPage.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, that's what I'm doing. Put that as an answer and I'll give you a tick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to duplicate the TabPage, the easiest path is to create a UserControl and just dock fill it into a new TabPage:

```
TabPage tabPage = new TabPage() { Text = "New Tab" };
tabPage.Controls.Add(new MyUserControl() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
```